# Error while accessing list with SharePoint WebService

Tags: web-services, sharepoint, list

I am trying to access the SharePoint List with web service and I need to update the same via web service accordingly. Following is the sample code that I am using

```
        Lists Testlist = new Lists();

        Testlist.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials; 

        Testlist.PreAuthenticate = true;

        XmlNode myNode = Testlist.GetList("sample list");  
        .
        .
        .
```

However I am getting Exception of type 'Microsoft.SharePoint.SoapServer.SoapServerException' when I try to use Testlist.getList() Method of web service.

I have goggled for it a lot but still not getting proper solution for the same.

Can any one help me out to solve this issue... :(

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you've set up your web service proxy by adding a WCF service reference; I have tried this route before and have not had success. In fact, I bet we even get the same error; mine was a problem authenticating to the service.

Once I regenerated my proxy using the non-WCF method (adding a Web Reference), I was able to get everything working with no problems.

You do this by adding a Service Reference to your project the same way you did before, except on the ["Add Service Reference" dialog](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386382.aspx), click the "Advanced..." button. This opens the ["Service Reference Settings" dialog](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb514724.aspx).

Here, click the ["Add Web Reference..."](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8dcbc50t.aspx) button at the bottom, then point to your Lists service and generate your proxy classes.

In code, after you instantiate your `Lists` service object, use the following for authentication:

```
TestList.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
```

Now you should be able to call your methods without exceptions. If you ever stumble across a proper way to authenticate to SharePoint web services using a Visual Studio Service Reference, I'd love to hear about it.